# Windows 8 index photos on NAS and show in Photos app

Tags: windows, photos

I have most of my photos on a NAS drive on the same network, just got a Windows 8 laptop and wanted to link my photos folder on the NAs drive to the Windows 8 photos app, anyone have a clue how to do this. I really want to avoid copying the folder to the local drive.